# cannot use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I'm trying to use the namespace  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` and implement the code [here](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/5cd1b721-9b94-4ea0-bd6e-2bb157401069/)

But Office is marked with a zig-zag red line as a not identified type

Any one know how should I include this library ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get and include the interop assemblies from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference in your project. Go to Solution Explorer, right-click "References", choose "Add reference..." and pick the appropiate reference, e.g. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.

Answer (score 0):

You should have Microsoft office installed on your machine